# How do I translate the feed of the group? in Workplace Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

In our group **feed content is automatically translated to eng to be shown in Workplace**, thanks to the workplace auto translate, but in **graph feed request you get only native language**.
How do I get translated feed aka. localised to english/
I have a simple request ->

```
GET "https://graph.facebook.com/group-id/feed?access_token="token""
```

Where do I put locale attribute or is it even possible to translate a feed?

Comment: `locale` just gets passed as an additional parameter, so you can put it into the query string here. Whether that will actually give translated posts in this situation though, don’t know, you’d have to check.

Comment: Try adding the query string params like `locale=en_US`

Comment: adding the `locale=en_US` parameter doesn't do the trick, the message is still in native language.